# How can I replace accents when there is a change in the workbook in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a macro.

I need to automatically change the accents (if exists) when a value is inserted into a cell, for example change "León" to "Leon". I'm trying to implement this in the **Worksheet_Change** function, but it doesn't work. Any idea how to do this?

I'm trying to replace this words, if exists in the word inserted into the workbook

```
Private sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error Resume Next

rowEl = Target.Row
colEl = Target.Column

if(Left(Cells(rowEl, colEl).Formula,1)<> “=”)  Then Cells(rowEl, colEl) =UCase(Cells(rowEl, colEl))

Dim int As Range, t As String
Set intr = Intersect(rowEl, colEl)

If intr Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

For Each r in intr
    t= Replace((r.Text, “ó”),”o”,”)
    Next r
End Sub
```

BR

Comment: ^^ This. How can we help you with your code if you don't show your code??

Comment: Sorry my friends, I already include my code. The section to convert to upper case works well, but my problem is that I don't know how to replace automatically accents on the whole sheet when insert a new value on any cell.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim chdCell As Range
Dim strval As String

For Each chdCell In Target.Cells
    strval = chdCell.Value
    strval = Replace(strval, "ó", "o")
    'add more replace as needed here before copying back to the cell
    chdCell.Value = strval
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Cell As Range
    
    For Each Cell In Target
    
        If Cell.HasFormula = False Then
        
            If TypeName(Cell.Value2) = "String" Then
            
                Cell = ClearText(Cell.Value2)
            
            End If
        
        End If
    
    Next Cell

End Sub

Function ClearText(Text As String) As String

    Dim ReturnText As String
    
    ReturnText = Text
    
    ReturnText = Replace(ReturnText, "á", "a")
    ReturnText = Replace(ReturnText, "é", "e")
    ReturnText = Replace(ReturnText, "í", "i")
    ReturnText = Replace(ReturnText, "ó", "o")
    ReturnText = Replace(ReturnText, "ú", "u")
    ' etc
    ' etc
    ' ...
    
    ClearText = ReturnText
    
End Function
```